# ¿Cómo encontrar elementos en una etiqueta de script de una página de origen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Quiero detectar automáticamente el event_name, el event_id y el id del conjunto de datos. Todos ellos están ocultos en el  de la página de origen. Hasta ahora sé cómo conseguir el guión:

```
import re

my_event_main_page_address = 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official'
# El siguiente enlace da a todos los distritos ids como "shapes". Se carga cuando se carga my_shape_id_address 
my_shape_id_address = 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official'
main_page = s.get(my_event_main_page_address)
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page.text, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find("script")

print(script)
```

Que devuelve :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.gon={};gon.is_mobile=false;gon.is_bot=false;gon.is_ie=false;gon.no_data_text="No Data";gon.no_data_color="#CCCCCC";gon.tile_url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png";gon.openlayers_img_path="/assets/img/";gon.datatable_i18n_url="";gon.is_voters_list=false;gon.shape_path="/en/json/shape/69898/shape_type/1";gon.children_shapes_path="/en/json/custom_children_shapes/69898/shape_type/3";gon.data_path="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official";gon.indicator_menu_data_path_summary="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator_type/xxx?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official";gon.indicator_menu_data_path="/en/json/custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator/xxx?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official";gon.summary_view_type_name="summary";gon.indicator_description="District Winners";gon.event_id="38";gon.event_name="2013 Presidential";gon.map_title="Country: Georgia - Districts";gon.parent_shape_id="69898";gon.data_type="official";gon.data_type_live="live";gon.data_set_id="111";gon.data_set_id_most_recent=111;gon.history_url="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape_type/1/shape/69898/indicator_type/2/view_type/summary/custom_view/true";gon.history_id=2;gon.data_table_path="/en/data_table/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1/child_shape_type/3/indicator/null/view_type/summary/summary_view_type/summary/custom_view/true?data_set_id=111&data_type=official&ind_order_explanation=Country%3A+Georgia&indicator_type_id=2";gon.dt_highlight_shape=false;gon.indicator_menu_scale=true;gon.openlayers=true;
//]]>
</script>
```

Así que uno puede ver que el `event_name` es `event_name="2013 Presidential"` pero no sé cómo agarrarlo. Hasta ahora he intentado usar la expresión regular:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\.val\("event_name"\);', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
event_name = soup.find("script", pattern = pattern)
print(event_name)
```

Pero devuelve `None`

Comment: ¿Por qué tu expresión regular intenta buscar `.val("event_name")` cuando el javascript muestra que lo que en realidad buscas es `gon.event_name="..."`?

Comment: Hola @abulafia !! espero que estés bien!! Era sólo una idea, no sé mucho sobre Regex.

Comment: @abulafia Intente `pattern = re.compile(r'gon.event_name\("(.*?)"\)')` pero me devuelve `None` tambien con `event_name = soup.find("script", pattern = pattern)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás usar el `.find()` de BeautifulSoup no es lo adecuado aqui, pues creo (no estoy seguro) que sólo busca en los nombres de los tags, pero no en su contenido.

Pero el contenido ya lo tienes en `script.text`, por lo que puedes usar la biblioteca `re` de Python para extraer el trozo que te interesa:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'gon.event_name="(.*?)"')
result = pattern.findall(script.text)
```

`result` será una lista cuyos elementos son todos los grupos hallados según la expresión regular (el grupo sería lo que va entre paréntesis, que indica en este caso cualquier secuencia de caracteres dentro de las comillas). En tu caso sólo se halla una coincidencia, que estará por tanto en `result[0]`:

```
>>> result[0]
'2013 Presidential'
```