# Cómo extraer datos de respuesta XHR del sitio web?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests, http-post

Quiero conseguir un enlace que una página web descargue después de haber sido cargada.

[image: ![![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desafortunadamente no puedo encontrar el enlace en la página de origen.

Hasta ahora he intentado esto:

```
import requests
import json

data = {
  "Device[udid]": "",
  "API_KEY": "",
  "API_SECRET": "",
  "Device[change]": "",
  "fbToken": ""
}

headers = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official"

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
data = r.json()
```

Pero devuelve un error de decodificación json..:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-189954289109> in <module>
     17 
     18 r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
---> 19 data = r.json()
     20 
     21 print(data["coins"])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    895                     # used.
    896                     pass
--> 897         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    898 
    899     @property

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: esto es lo que buscabas? [data](https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official)

Comment: @Bryro Sí, pero me gustaría automatizarlo. Porque hay elecciones donde los distritos son son completamente diferentes como [esta](https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/50/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official).

Comment: ¿No habías hecho una pregunta muy similar hace poco? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/298232/7123

Comment: @abulafia ha, no estaba buscando por la misma cosa en esta pregunta, estaba buscando por los tags. No sabia que fue en el script que podría obtener el vinculo en el script tambien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te descargas mediante tu petición a `requests.post()` no es JSON, sino HTML, por lo que no es de extrañar que falle el intento de `r.json()` (esto serviría para convertir a tipos de datos python la respuesta del servidor, si ésta hubiera sido de tipo JSON, pero no lo es como acabo de decir).

Además, no veo por qué descargas la página inicial con un POST. Eso no funciona pues devuelve una página distinta de la que muestras en tu captura de pantalla, y que no contiene lo que necesitamos. Si le haces un GET en cambio no hay problema y recibes la misma página que muestras en tu navegador.

El navegador, una vez descargada esa página, ejecuta código javascript que hay en ella y realiza una petición XHR (ajax), que es la que descarga el JSON que buscas.

La URL de la que descarga el JSON no forma parte del HTML de la página, sino de su código javascript. Esto en general puede ser más difícil de localizar (pues no se puede usar por ejemplo BeautifulSoup para localizar elementos tipo `<a>`), pero en este caso hay suerte porque el javascript en cuestión es visible como parte del HTML (podría ser peor, y  estar en otro fichero .js descargado desde una referencia). Aparece aquí:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.gon={};gon.is_mobile=false;gon.is_bot=false;gon.is_ie=false;gon.no_data_text="No Data";gon.no_data_color="#CCCCCC";gon.tile_url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png";gon.openlayers_img_path="/assets/img/";gon.datatable_i18n_url="";gon.is_voters_list=false;gon.shape_path="/en/json/shape/69898/shape_type/1";gon.children_shapes_path="/en/json/custom_children_shapes/69898/shape_type/3";gon.data_path="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official";gon.indicator_menu_data_path_summary="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator_type/xxx?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official";gon.indicator_menu_data_path="/en/json/custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator/xxx?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official";gon.summary_view_type_name="summary";gon.indicator_description="District Winners";gon.event_id="38";gon.event_name="2013 Presidential";gon.map_title="Country: Georgia - Districts";gon.parent_shape_id="69898";gon.data_type="official";gon.data_type_live="live";gon.data_set_id="111";gon.data_set_id_most_recent=111;gon.history_url="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape_type/1/shape/69898/indicator_type/2/view_type/summary/custom_view/true";gon.history_id=2;gon.data_table_path="/en/data_table/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1/child_shape_type/3/indicator/null/view_type/summary/summary_view_type/summary/custom_view/true?data_set_id=111&data_type=official&ind_order_explanation=Country%3A+Georgia&indicator_type_id=2";gon.dt_highlight_shape=false;gon.indicator_menu_scale=true;gon.openlayers=true;
//]]>
</script>
```

donde puedes ver el trocito donde se asigna la URL que buscas a una variable javascript:

```
gon.data_path="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/69898/shape_type/3/event/38/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=111&data_type=official"
```

Por tanto en este caso puedes aplicar una expresión regular al HTML, para extraer ese fragmento de ruta. Después, concatenas ese fragmento al nombre del host para tener la URL completa y poder hacerle otro GET.

El siguiente ejemplo funciona perfectamente:

```
import requests
import json
import re

host = "https://data.electionsportal.ge"
url = host + "/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official"
r = requests.get(url)

data_path =re.findall(r"gon.data_path=\"(.*?)\"", r.text)
if not data_path:
  print("Error, no se encuentra la URL buscada")
else:
  data_path = data_path[0]  # Si hubo resultado, tomar el primero
  r2 = requests.get(host + data_path)
  print(r2.json())
```